# SQL performance advice

Tags: sql-server

I know that it can be a tricky question and that it highly depends on context.

I have a database with a table containing around 10 millions lines (each line contains 4 varchar).
There is an index non clustered on the field (a varchar) used for the where.

I'm a bit confused because when selecting a line using a where on the indexed columns, it takes around a second to end.

Any advices to improve this response time ? 
Would an indexed clustered be a good solution here?

Here is the table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MYTABLE](
[ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
[CreationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
[UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
[FIELD1] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
[FIELD2] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[FIELD3] [varchar](1) NULL,
[FIELD4] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_MYTABLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the index definition :

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FIELD1] ON [dbo].[MYTABLE]
(
[FIELD1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

And here is the query I use (very basic) :

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE FIELD1 = 'DATA'
```

Comment: You said "I know that it can be a tricky question and that it highly depends on context." And then you proceed to ask a question that requires a very detailed answer but provided almost no context. What are you expecting for an answer here? Are you saying your table has no clustered index and has 10 million rows? How about posting the table definition including indexes and the query you are trying?

Comment: @SeanLange Well, that's a good advice ;) I've just edited my question to add definitions

Comment: Go ahead and [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). If SQL Server thinks `FIELD1 = 'DATA'` is very selective (per the index statistics), you'll see an index seek using the `IX_FIELD1` index followed by a clustered index lookup for all the other columns. Otherwise, you'll see a clustered index scan. The former tends to be fast, but it depends greatly on how many rows your query actually returns, whether your table is fragmented, and whether the plan involves (possibly inappropriate) parallelization. Absolute execution time depends on I/O speed (`SET STATISTICS IO ON`).

Comment: Slightly off topic but you have a uniqueidentifier as your clustered index. This is a bad idea because it gets fragmented horribly with just a few thousand rows. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/ But I wouldn't be too surprised if fragmentation is a large part of the issue here.

Comment: That's very much on topic, I'd say, because a heavily fragmented clustered index would be a really good way to slow this query down even with the search fields indexed. :-)

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, it was really interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, since you are selecting all columns (`*`), changing your nonclustered index to a clustered one will improve the time, since accessing additional columns (columns not included in the index, not ordered nor by `INCLUDE`) from a nonclustered index will need to retrieve another page with the actual data.

Since you can't have more than 1 clustered index by table, you will have to drop the existing one (the `PRIMARY KEY` in this case) and create it afterwards.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MYTABLE DROP [PK_MYTABLE] -- This might fail if you have foreign keys

ALTER TABLE dbo.MYTABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MYTABLE PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ID) 

DROP INDEX [IX_FIELD1] ON [dbo].[MYTABLE]

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FIELD1] ON [dbo].[MYTABLE] (FIELD1)
```

Indexes access times might greatly vary depending on their fragmentation also (if you have many inserts, deletes or updates with values that aren't bigger or lower than the last/first one).

Also keep in mind that if you are doing another operation like joins, function calls or additional `WHERE` filters, the enging might decide not to use the indexes.

Comment: Thanks ! it took almost 3 minutes to reordered whole table but now requests take much less time to execute (around 200ms nevertheless)

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that the column used in your `WHERE` clause is unique, you may create a [UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql) on that column.

If values in that column are not unique, you can implement [COVERING INDEXES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns). For example, if you had this index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Column4 ON MyTable(Column4)
INCLUDE (Column1, Column2);
```

When executing the following query:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM MyTable WHERE Column4 LIKE 'Something';
```

You would (most likely) be using the `IX_Column4` index. But when executing something like:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM MyTable WHERE Column4 LIKE 'Something';
```

You will not be benefited from the advantages that this kind of index have to offer.

If rows in your table are regurlarly `INSERTED, DELETED or UPDATED` you should check for [INDEX FRAGMENTATION and REBUILD or REORGANIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes) them.

I would recommend the following articles in case you want to lear more about indexes:

- [Available index types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes#available-index-types), check out the guidelines offered for each kind of index.
- [SQL Server Index Design Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095(v=sql.110).aspx)

Hope it helps.